# Changing startup parameters for MySQL

Tags: linux, mysql, centos

I need to remove **skip-networking** from MySQL startup parameters

I am running MySQL on Linux on Centos on a VPS

Can someone please tell a newbie how to do this ?

I suppose to start and stop the mySQL server, I have to do something like this
 /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
 /etc/init.d/mysqld start

```
# ps -ef|grep 'mysql'  
root     11331 20220  0 10:53 pts/0    00:00:00 grep mysql  
root     32452     1  0 Apr02 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking  
mysql    32504 32452  0 Apr02 ?        00:00:18 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-external-locking --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the `/etc/init.d/mysqld` script, find the `--skip-networking` parameter and remove it.

Comment: Just checked. That file doesn't have this parameter

Comment: Try running this query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'skip_networking';`. If it's set to ON you might not have your port configured in the my.cnf.

Comment: It is ON. Checked my /etc/my.cnf. It doesn't have a port defined.

Basically, I am trying to troubleshoot http://serverfault.com/questions/129038/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-from-java-application

Comment: Add `port = 3306` in my.cnf and `bind-address = YOUR_IP` and try again.

Comment: All I did was add the port to my.cnf. Did not add bind-address.

Answer (score 6):

comment the "skip-networking" directive in /etc/my.cnf and restart mysqld.

You can specify other networking related directives in my.cnf, Example:

```
[mysqld]
user = mysql
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port = 3306
basedir = /usr
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir = /tmp
language = /usr/share/mysql/English
bind-address = 172.20.5.2
# skip-networking
```

Restart with:

```
service mysqld restart
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the white rabbit. At some point, originating from /etc/init.d/mysqld, some script must append the parameter. If existing, check /usr/bin/mysqld_safe. Also look at included files in these scripts.

Maybe we're tampering with a security measure here. Does CentOS add this line unless a password has been set for the mysql root user?

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you are also trying it as root. I got the same problem, and this tweak helped me:

Change this line in /etc/my.cnf

```
"user=mysql"
```

to

```
"user=root"
```

Comment: It's really bad advice. You should avoid running daemons as root for secuirty reasons.

Comment: agreed... but this is b'coz of the conflict in new MySQL Release and User Permission... 
And the Person here most probably is trying that as ROOT
So, i replied the least confusing reply where he/she wouldn't have to change anything else he/she is doing
...................
otherwise he/she could login as the new 'mysql' gets created and do the changing... or change the "user=root" with any low-priority user to access it